# How do I replace a sequence of placeholder images in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, automation

I have a Google Doc document featuring a series of placeholder images. I need to replace each image with a series of images from a local folder. In theory, this is a meaningless task, but so far, my efforts have been fruitless. I have looked through a few documents, including a few *'tips for google docs'* styled blog posts; but nothing seems to cover my explicit requirements.

[image]

I have 160+ images, and thus I would prefer an automated method rather than manually replacing each image separately. Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some great amount of research and observation of other Google Docs practices, I have come to the realisation that you simply can not.

As a pseudo fix, I docked the window next to the folder containing these images. While slightly tedious, the manual automation of this task did not nearly take as long as I had of predicted, and I was able to complete it thoughtlessly, while watching some Doctor Who.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably script this, but there's no easy way to do it already in Docs.